# Выбор наиболее специфичного типа аргумента при вызове перегруженного метода в Java

Tags: java, наследование

Известно, что если при удовлетворении сразу нескольких перегруженных методов вызову, выберется тот, аргумент которого наиболее специфичен. Пример:

```
class Test {
    void t(Object o) {System.out.println("Object");}
    void t(Integer i) {System.out.println("Integer");}
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        new Test().t(null);
    }
}
```

В данном случае выдастся то, что и должно - Integer (Integer имеет 1 уровень наследования от Object). Если же добавить ещё 3 метод с аргументом String, произойдёт ошибка, т. к. у Integer и у String уровень наследования равняется 1.
Теперь рассмотрим другой пример:

```
class B1 {}
class E1 extends B1 {}
class EE1 extends E1 {}
class B2 {}
class Test {
    void t(B2 e) {System.out.println("B2");}
    void t(EE1 e) {System.out.println("EE1");}
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        new Test().t(null);
    }
}
```

Если попробовать его запустить, произойдёт ошибка, не удалось выбрать наиболее специфичный тип! Хотя в случае EE1 имеется 3 уровня наследования, а у B2 1 уровень наследования.
И финальный пример:

```
class B1 {}
class E1 extends B1 {}
class EE1 extends E1 {}
class Test {
    void t(E1 e) {System.out.println("E1");}
    void t(EE1 e) {System.out.println("EE1");}
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        new Test().t(null);
    }
}
```

Отрабатывает корректно. Выдаётся EE1. 
С чем связано такое поведение? Почему при ветвлении наследования не происходит определения специфичности на основании удалённости от Object?

Comment: "Почему при ветвлении наследования не происходит определения специфичности на основании удалённости от Object?" - а почему вы решили что должно быть именно так и не иначе?

Comment: Есть такое подозрение, что глубина наследования не имеет значения. Где вы такое прочли?

Comment: Не всё учёл. Думал, что раз корнем иерархии выступает Object, то специфичность определятся минимальной длиной пути в наследовании от Object (то бишь от корня).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать выбор *только* между базовым классом и наследником (можно через другой класс) в пользу наследника. Между 2 *любыми* наследниками из разных "веток" выбор сделать нельзя.

Вас же не удивил пример 1 после добавления `String`, `Integer` наследуется от `Number` и является наследником 2 порядка и по вашей логике должен выбираться именно он. Хотя такое поведение было бы, мягко говоря, странным.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё понятно (про Number забыл напрочь).